# How to fix memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, delete-operator

I am working on the project which using pointer (new ext...) and I don't know how to fix it, I couldn't use the delete syntax because it will break the code literally.

```
list<Virus*> DoClone() 
{
    list<Virus*> l;

    Dengue *d1 = new Dengue(1), *d2 = new Dengue(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        d1->m_protein[i] = m_protein[i];
    d1->m_dna = m_dna;
    d1->m_resistance = m_resistance;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        d2->m_protein[i] = m_protein[i];
    d2->m_dna = m_dna;
    d2->m_resistance = m_resistance;

    l.emplace_back(d1);
    l.emplace_back(d2);
    //delete d1;
    //delete d2;
    return l;
}

void DoDie()
{
    this->m_dna = NULL;
    memset(this->m_protein, 0, 4);
    this->m_resistance = 0;
    delete this->m_dna;
}
```

Comment: `delete` is the only way to fix a memory leak. If using `delete` breaks your code then it is because you have a bug somewhere else in your code and you should fix that bug.

Comment: Obviously the two commented out deletes in `DoClone` are wrong, because those pointers are on the list you are returning. But to fix the leak you need to add some deletes somewhere else in your code. But it's not possible to say where from the code you have posted.

Comment: Don't use raw pointers and you won;t have to `delete` anything. Try using `std::unique_ptr<Virus>`.

Comment: Unrelated: implementing the copy constructor and assignment operator would allow you to write `Dengue *d1 = new Dengue(*this)`

Comment: Where do you call the `DoClone()` function? which variable is holding the returned vector of `DoClone()`? When you want to release memory, try to loop through that variable and call `delete` for each item.

Comment: You need to delete those when you're done with them. That's probably when you're done with the list that holds the pointers. (If it's more complicated than that, I would recommend rethinking things and spending more effort on thinking about object lifetimes.)

Comment: Make sure `Virus` has a virtual destructor. https://isocpp.org/blog/2019/08/quick-q-when-to-use-virtual-destructors

Comment: thanks y'all for fast solutions you gave me, now i'll try to fix it, really appriciate it

Comment: BTW, name of the method `DoClone` lies! It doesn't clone current object, it creates list of some two items.

Comment: Doing `delete this->m_dna` after `this->m_dna=NULL` does not really do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

Smart pointers to the rescue:

```cpp
list<std::unique_ptr<Virus>> DoClone() 
{
    list<std::unique_ptr<Virus>> l;

    auto d1 = std::make_unique<Dengue>(1);
    auto d2 = std::make_unique<Dengue>(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        d1->m_protein[i] = m_protein[i];

    d1->m_dna = m_dna;
    d1->m_resistance = m_resistance;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        d2->m_protein[i] = m_protein[i];
    d2->m_dna = m_dna;
    d2->m_resistance = m_resistance;

    l.emplace_back(std::move(d1));
    l.emplace_back(std::move(d2));

    return l;
}

void DoDie()
{
    m_dna.reset();
    memset(this->m_protein, 0, 4);
    this->m_resistance = 0;
}
```

It would be best if you learn to use smart pointers ASAP. [Here is good lecture](https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE) on topic.

Also see:
[C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-owner)

> #### R.20: Use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` to represent ownership
>
> ###### Reason
>
> They can prevent resource leaks.
>
> ###### Example
>
> Consider:
>
> ```
> void f()
> {
>     X x;
>     X* p1 { new X };              // see also ???
>     unique_ptr<X> p2 { new X };   // unique ownership; see also ???
>     shared_ptr<X> p3 { new X };   // shared ownership; see also ???
>     auto p4 = make_unique<X>();   // unique_ownership, preferable to the explicit use "new"
>     auto p5 = make_shared<X>();   // shared ownership, preferable to the explicit use "new"
> }
> ```
>
> This will leak the object used to initialize `p1` (only).
>
> ###### Enforcement
>
> (Simple) Warn if the return value of `new` or a function call with return value of pointer type is assigned to a raw pointer.

**Extra:**

small refactor:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Dengue> createDengue(int x)
{
    auto d = std::make_unique<Dengue>(x);
    d->m_protein = m_protein; // someone claims this is an std::array so loop is not needed
    d->m_dna = m_dna;
    d->m_resistance = m_resistance;
    return d;
}

list<std::unique_ptr<Virus>> DoClone() 
{
    list<std::unique_ptr<Virus>> l;
    l.emplace_back(createDengue(1));
    l.emplace_back(createDengue(1));
    return l;
}

void DoDie()
{
    m_dna.reset();
    this->m_protein = {}; // someone claims this is an std::array so  this is fine
    this->m_resistance = 0;
}
```

Comment: If m_protein is a std::array, or std::vector these can be just copied without the for loops.

Comment: Where this is stated?

Answer (score 0):

```
list<Virus*> DoClone() 
{
    //Why are you using a list of pointers?
    //Are you handing these out?
    list<Virus*> l; // Replace list<Virus> l or use smart pointers

    Dengue *d1 = new Dengue(1), *d2 = new Dengue(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        d1->m_protein[i] = m_protein[i];
    }
    //if the move semantics of any of them are wrong your code will crash, 
    //but you don't show us what these are.
    d1->m_dna = m_dna;
    d1->m_resistance = m_resistance;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        d2->m_protein[i] = m_protein[i];
    d2->m_dna = m_dna;
    d2->m_resistance = m_resistance;

    l.emplace_back(d1);
    l.emplace_back(d2);

    //You definitely shouldn't be deleting these you jsut gave them to a container to hold!
    //delete d1;
    //delete d2;
    return l;
}

void DoDie(ist<Virus*>& myList)
{
    //You set this to nullptr, but try to delete it in 4 lines time. This looks like a leak
    //Also the fact it was a pointer means you definitely copied it wrong above
    //use std::shared_ptr or std::weak_ptr if you want to share things.
    this->m_dna = NULL;
    memset(this->m_protein, 0, 4);
    
    this->m_resistance = 0;
    delete this->m_dna;

    //Lastly you need to free the memory in your container
    for(auto* item : myList){
     delete item;
    }
    myList.clear();

}
```